# WPF how can I get the defined public variable of the parent to the child

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried the VisualTreehelper and the

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(ConfigUserControl);
```

and the

```
UIElement parent = Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

but I couldn't see my public variable that I declared in the MainWindow

```
public UserMgr fUserMgr = new UserMgr();
```

I'm using fUserMgr as a reference for the audit trail where in I'll get the user that is logged in then put it in the CreatedBy field of my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to typecast the Window to your window class as

```
var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(ConfigUserControl) as MYWINDOWCLASS;

if(parentWindow != null)
{
   //Can access UserMgr on parentWindow
   parentWindow.fUserMgr 
}
```